# How to fetch latest record using flexible search query?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have two attributes A & B as below. I want to fetch latest record from each set of duplicate record's based on creation time.

I tried doing it with MAX function but flexible search is not supporting MAX function. Any help would be appreciated?

```
  Table : ABC

A B

100 11

100 11

100 11

200 12

200 12

300 13



 Result :

100 11

200 12

300 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `max` function. Please use it as given below

```
SELECT max({modifiedtime}) FROM {Product}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select rows with MAX(creationTime) but DISTINCT by column A in SQL then you can try something like this

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ABC t1
JOIN
({{

SELECT {aCol}, MAX(creationTime) AS maxDateTime
    FROM ABC
    GROUP BY {aCol}

}}) as t2

ON t1.aCol = t2.aCol 
AND t1.creationTime = t2.maxDateTime
```